# PHP date comparison giving unintended results

Tags: php, strtotime, date-arithmetic, date-comparison

I am formatting dates to American style format `mm/dd/yyyy` (without time) and comparing the dates but not getting expected results.

```
echo $startDate ;  // 09/14/2018
echo $nextDate ;   // 03/08/2019
echo $stopDate ;   // 03/08/2019
```

The above variables are being created in the following fashion:

```
$nextDate = date('m/d/Y',strtotime("today")) ;
```

And then comparing dates as:

```
if ($nextDate >= $startDate && $nextDate <= $stopDate) {
  ...
  do stuff
  ...
}
```

`$nextDate` is greater than `$startdate` and is equal to `$stopDate` but its not making it inside the IF statement.  What am I missing here?

Comment: You compare __strings__ and not __dates__.

Comment: To add on to @u_mulder's comment - why not just compare the date objects themselves?

Comment: Compare the timestamps and only format when you want to display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it this way with `strtotime()`,

```
$startDate = strtotime($startDate);
$stopDate= strtotime($stopDate);
$nextDate =strtotime("today");

if ($nextDate >= $startDate && $nextDate <= $stopDate) {
  ...
  do stuff
  ...
}
```

**WORKING DEMO:** https://3v4l.org/BWZN5

Comment: Thanks.  This worked.  I didn't realize `date` was converting things to literal strings.  Someone above down voted me for my question to...bad form on them.

Comment: Glad it helps you somehow, happy coding.